# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debug Error in Eclipse dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

First of all I want to say that I have searched for this extensively, but haven't found a solution by trying the following solutions.

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/CoreMessageLogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903425/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-internal-coremessagelogger)

[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595237/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-internal-coremessagelogger-debugflja)

[Hibernate exception found in calling buildsessionfactory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669510/hibernate-exception-found-in-calling-buildsessionfactory-method-pls-help-me)

[Jersey REST web service with Hibernate causes NoSuchMethodError on JBoss EAP 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799515/jersey-rest-web-service-with-hibernate-causes-nosuchmethoderror-on-jboss-eap-6-4)

These are the tops in Google. Most of them doesn't even have a accepted answer and the one that has I tried that but of no use.

Now I want to describe what I am doing. So you can either solve the error or show me another way. I am open to suggestion.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2.

I created a Dynamic Web Project. My target is to configure hibernate and save a User(Entity) in the doGet() method of a servlet just to test my hibernate configuration is working.

First I added the Hibernate 5.0.5 as a user library in my build path, I added all the required jars of hibernate. Then when I tried to run, the error occured.

By following one of the suggestions, I also added hibernate in Deployment Assembly so when it deployed it will be in WEB-INF/lib. But it didn't work.

By following another suggestion I removed the jboss logging jar which came with hibernate and added the glassfish jboss logging. Didn't work.

Note: I am using glassfish 4.1.

And also if you think my hibernate testing process is wrong I am open to any suggestions. Thanks.

The complete stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:34)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at com.th.controllers.PullDataAndShow.doGet(PullDataAndShow.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you share your complete stack track? It will help me to figure the the root cause.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Added the complete stack trace

Comment: Thx, Its conflict of jar files.
Solution : Use jar files of your server glassfish 4.1, if it does not have any jar file which you need then externally you can set it on your build path. but give first priority to your servers' jar files.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Sorry just saw the answer. I am going to try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you concern with you hibernate configuration, use hibernate perspective and run HQL there, if your HQL works fine that means your hibernate configuration is fine. Once you sure then you can proceed with your actual business process in project.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed The conflict of jar made me think if I change the version of hibernate then maybe the problem will be solved. So I switched to hibernate 4.2.23. And the problem went away. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: sounds good :) you did great job (y)